# Is there a script which will detect camera-shake blur?

Tags: software, blur, camera-shake, plugin

Is there any existing script, either standalone (python, perl, etc.) or bridge/aperture plug-in that will detect blur of the type where you move the camera when taking the picture?  I know this can be done, but can't find a way that exists to easily do it.  I just want camera-shake detection, *not* removal.

Comment: Do you want to be alerted to the presence of such blur, or do you need to know the characteristics (how much, in which direction)?

Comment: Do you mean from a single picture? And how do you know that it can be done? This strikes me as a very tough problem, if you're not doing it using multiple images or mechanically.

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~htong/pdf/ICME04_tong.pdf

Comment: What's your programming / math background?  If you're sufficiently ambitious and patient, you may get more mileage out of higher-level tools like Mathematica / Maple / Matlab, since the algorithm will likely involve matrix math to "convolve" the image with "kernels" (represented as matrices) to perform edge detection, and there may be a Fourier transform or Hough transform thrown in there somewhere.  Anyways, getting an answer for this type of thing is well beyond normal photography topics and might be terrific fun for the Math StackExchange.  I'm voting to move it.

Comment: There's also a Digital Signal Processing StackExchange that might be able to tackle this: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a signal processing question (although it is also kind of a mathematic convolution problem as well), however DSP is still in beta. We could move it there, but migrations to beta sites is kind of discouraged, as if they don't make it out of beta, migrated questions can be lost. I'll see about moving it to MathSE if its really appropriate there.

Comment: I'm going to close this question for now. It doesn't really belong on this particular site, but were not really sure where it does belong. There have not been any good answers provided so far, and I'm not sure there will be. I think DSP might be the best place, and perhaps we should simply move it there despite it being in beta.

Answer (score -2):

Adobe recently did a presentation of a new technology which not only tracks shake, but can reverse it as well.   They said it won't be in CS6, maybe 7 or there after.  If you search on youtube you should be able to find it.

Comment: This is very true - though its unclear exactly how the camera shake / blur mask is "defined". I'd refer the original poster to search for information/plugins on deconvolution such as the Lucy Richardson approach IF they want to try remove camera shake. However the original poster seems to want to just detect it and classify the blur?

Comment: I know.  Don't want that, just the detection, which already exists.